# creating html output file with plot bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

as a very simple example when I want to export a visualisation to a html in bokeh i'd do something like this:

```
#importing bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

#data prep
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]

#prep output file
output_file('line.html')

#create a figure object
f=figure()

#create a line plot
f.square(x,y)

show(f)
```

which seems to work fine.

however when working with a visualisation like a histogram and when working with pandas_bokeh i cant get it to export as a html. for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

df['any random numerical column'].plot_bokeh(kind='hist',)
output_file('hist.html')
```

anyone know how i can get this to work?

my second question is, is how would I export a viz if I was using holoviews? as in how can the code be altered here: http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/boxplot_chart.html for it to be done?

any light shed on these 2 questions would be greatly appreciated and please explain as simply as possible as this is all fairly new to me. thank you

Comment: As a kind of a workaround you can run this code in the Jupyter Notebook and export this notebook as HTML.

Comment: I have been using Jupyter to run the code, however its not exporting as a html. any help?

Comment: And how is it exporting? Is there an error? Are you using File -> Download as -> HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

To quote form the documentation for [`output_file()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=output#bokeh.io.output_file):

> `output_file()` creates an output to a file when [`show()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=output#bokeh.io.show) is called.

Another option is to call [`save()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=output#bokeh.io.save) after `output_file()` to create the HTML-File.

**Example for pandas-bokeh**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh
from bokeh.io import output_file, save
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[3,4,2,1,3]})
p = df.plot_bokeh()

output_file('lines.html')
save(p)
```

Since `show()` is called inside `pandas-bokeh` anyway an even shorter example to generate the same figure is:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh
from bokeh.io import output_file
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

output_file('lines.html')
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[3,4,2,1,3]})
df.plot_bokeh()
```

**Holoviews**

For holoviews there exists the method [`hv.save()](https://holoviews.org/getting_started/Introduction.html?highlight=save#saving-and-rendering-objects) to genreate a html, too.

But you can also get the bokeh object by calling [`p = hv.render(fig)`](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plots_and_Renderers.html#saving-and-rendering) and do the same with the `save` from the `pandas-bokeh` example.

I didn't try it, but it is also possible that holoviews internally calls `show()` so the second example cloud also work.